# Change Output of PHP Script to use POST Method

Tags: php, xml, parsing, post

Bear with my inexperience here, but can anyone point me in the right direction for how I can change the PHP script below to output each variable that is parsed from the XML file (title, link, description, etc) as a POST method instead of just to an HTML page?

```
<?php
$html = "";
$url = "http://api.brightcove.com/services/library?command=search_videos&any=tag:SMGV&output=mrss&media_delivery=http&sort_by=CREATION_DATE:DESC&token= // this is where the API token goes";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true); // get namespaces

for($i = 0; $i < 80; $i++){
  $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->video;
  $link = $xml->channel->item[$i]->link;
  $title = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
  $pubDate = $xml->channel->item[$i]->pubDate;
  $description = $xml->channel->item[$i]->description;
  $titleid = $xml->channel->item[$i]->children($namespaces['bc'])->titleid;
  $html .= "<h3>$title</h3>$description<p>$pubDate<p>$link<p>Video ID: $titleid<p>
    <iframe width='480' height='270' src='http://link.brightcove.com/services/player/bcpid3742068445001?bckey=AQ~~,AAAABvaL8JE~,ufBHq_I6FnyLyOQ_A4z2-khuauywyA6P&bctid=$titleid&autoStart=false' frameborder='0'></iframe><hr/>";/* this embed code is from the youtube iframe embed code format but is actually using the embedded Ooyala player embedded on the Campus Insiders page. I replaced any specific guid (aka video ID) numbers with the "$guid" variable while keeping the Campus Insider Ooyala publisher ID, "eb3......fad" */
}
echo $html;
?>
```

@V.Radev Here's another PHP script using cURL that I think will work with the API I'm trying to send data to:

```
<?PHP
  $url = 'http://api.brightcove.com/services/post';

  //open connection
  $ch = curl_init($url);

  //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '$title,$descripton,$url' . stripslashes($_POST['$title,$description,$url']));
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  // Enable for Charles debugging
  //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888'); 

  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  print $result;
?>
```

My question is, how can I pass the variables from my feed parsing script (title, description, URL) to this new script?

I have this code from Brightcove, can I just output the variables from my parser script and send to this PHP script so that the data goes to the API?

```
<?php

  // This code example uses the PHP Media API wrapper
  // For the PHP Media API wrapper, visit http://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/open-source/index.html

  // Include the BCMAPI Wrapper
  require('bc-mapi.php');

  // Instantiate the class, passing it our Brightcove API tokens (read, then write)
  $bc = new BCMAPI(
    '[[READ_TOKEN]]',
    '[[WRITE_TOKEN]]'
  );

  // Create an array of meta data from our form fields
  $metaData = array(
    'name' => $_POST['bcVideoName'],
    'shortDescription' => $_POST['bcShortDescription']
  );

  // Move the file out of 'tmp', or rename
  rename($_FILES['videoFile']['tmp_name'], '/tmp/' . $_FILES['videoFile']['name']);
  $file = '/tmp/' . $_FILES['videoFile']['name'];

  // Create a try/catch
  try {
    // Upload the video and save the video ID
    $id = $bc->createMedia('video', $file, $metaData);
          echo 'New video id: ';
          echo $id;
  } catch(Exception $error) {
    // Handle our error
    echo $error;
    die();
  }
?>
```

Comment: Please research how to make a POST request with a PHP script, that topic should be covered sufficiently already.

Answer (score 0):

Post is a request method to access a specific page or resource. With echo you are sending data which means that you are responding. In this page you can only add response headers and access it with a request method such as post, get, put etc.

Edit for API request as mentiond in the comments:

```
$curl = curl_init('your api url');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $your_data_to_send);
$result_from_api = curl_exec($curl); 
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification on that, I'm assuming I would need to call something like cURL in this script in order to pass data via PUT or POST?

Comment: cURL is also a way to make requests. You are making a response. You can make a request to this file by post method, but you can't output it with post method. Can you give some details about what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I realize I have to change the script, just not sure how to do it. What I want to do is take all of the elements that this script is parsing from the feed, and send or post those elements (video title, description, URL) to a video cloud hosting service via their API. I'm just not experienced enough to know how to implement this last step. I have the API documentation, I know I need to use the POST method and a create_video command, but I don't know how to set that up.

Comment: For this API request cURL would be the preferred method indeed. Please check the changes to my answer above and note that you may need to json encode your sending data if it is required by the API. I added a returntransfer to the cURL options in case you are expecting a response from the API.

Comment: thanks again for your guidance man, I really appreciate it. See my updated post above, I took a stab at creating a PHP script which incorporates your recommendation and will I think will work with the API I'm trying to send this data to. My question is: how do you recommend I send the data from the parsing script to this new script that uses cURL?

Comment: Can't you combine the 2 scripts? Send request to the API and parse at one place. Or maybe extract the cURL request to a function and call it wherever you need.